# struct values are changing from one function to other in unexpected manner

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    unsigned char a[3];
    unsigned short data[3];
    unsigned int d1;
    unsigned int d2;
} abc; 

void f1(abc *ptr)
{
    printf("values are :0x%x  \t0x%x  \t0%x",ptr->data[0],ptr->data[1],ptr->data[2]);
    //Hex map of ptr  is given below (taken by  gdb --> x/20b ptr )
    //ptr-->0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x44 0x29 0xff 0xff
    //      0xff 0xff        
}
void f()
{
    abc req;
    req.a[0]=1;
    req.a[1]=0;
    req.a[2]=0;
    req.data[0]=0x2944;
    req.data[1]=0xffff;
    req.data[2]=0xffff;
    req.d1= 0xffff;
    req.d2= 0xffff;
    f1(&req);   

    //Hex map of req  is given below (taken by  gdb --> x/20b req )
    // req--> 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x44 0x29 0xff 0xff
    //        0xff 0xff    
}
int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I am working on the code sample given above . 
filling values in one struct in 1 function and passing struct to other function.
But values of struct are changed in the caller function. When I checked with gdb, struct byte representation is same.
But some how values are changed. Can any one explain what happened and how to overcome it
gcc version is 4.9.3 and gdb version is 7.7.1 and OS is ubuntu 14.

Below is the output from gdb.

```
req values in f() --> 
(gdb) p/x req
$1 = {
  a = {0x1, 0x0, 0x0},
  data = {0x2944, 0xffff, 0xffff},
  d1 = 0xffff,
  d2 = 0xffff

(gdb) x/20b &req
0xffffcb80:     0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x44    0x29    0xff    0xff


ptr values in f1()---->
(gdb) p/x *ptr
$1 = {
  a = {0x1, 0x0, 0x0},
  data = {0x4400, 0xff29, 0xffff},

  (gdb) x/20b ptr
0xffffcb80:     0x01    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x44    0x29    0xff    0xff
```

Comment: Is the `printf` printing the expected values?

Comment: My guess is that `p/x *ptr` includes the *padding* between members. Related question: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: @Some programmer dude I think you mean _excludes_.

Comment: Note there is one padding byte after the `char[3]`. Nothing is changed.

Comment: @meat *Includes* like in printing the padding bytes

Comment: You're right. Misinterpreted what he was saying.

Comment: I ran your code through gcc version 4.8.1 and also through an online gcc compiler and the code works fine. The output is what you desire.

Comment: Correct printf format for short is "hx"...

Comment: print is also not printing correct values.It looks padding is doing something wrong here. 
Same code when I run in home computer it is working fine.

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: @Aconcagua `short` in variadic argumens is promoted to `int` anyway

Comment: 0x4400    0xff29    0xfff 
This is the output

Comment: In f1() function , data is started 1 byte earlier.

Comment: Somehow I tend not to believe you.... Are you sure you are running the exact same code you have posted?

Comment: Eugene Sh :- Yes . same code is not working in office. Even I discussed this with my 4 to 5 colleague. None of them was able to explain the reason.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc 4.9.3 on Ubuntu 14 with gdb 7.7.1

Comment: Then it sounds like some compiler bug or, which is more likely, you are doing something wrong. Like not compiling after the change or something.

Comment: Yes it could be compiler bug. I will check again and come back

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one explain what happened

The most likely explanation is that

- the functions `f` and `f1` are in different translation units, and
- the definition of `struct abc` is *different* between them (for example, in one translation unit the struct has `__attribute__((packed))`, while in the other one it doesn't.

If so, this is an ODR (one definition rule) violation; your program is malformed, no compiler diagnostic required.

Printing `sizeof(struct abc)` in both `f` and `f1` is one way to confirm or disprove this guess.

If the sizes *are* different, then saving pre-processed output (`gcc -E`) and looking inside for how `struct abc` is defined will likely be illuminating.

Comment: @shekharsingh Rearranged in what way? Did you find the problem?